# How to get email id from below elements?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

How can I get the email ID using the send button? As any email can be transferred pressing the button so I think there might be any way to catch the request where it goes. I can't get any idea how my script should be to serve the purpose. Thanks for taking a look into it.

Picture of that email button from that page is like:

[image]

Html elements for Send Email lie within the below portion:

```
<div class="col-sm-19 businessCapsule--callToAction">
<a itemprop="url" href="/customerneeds/sendenquiry/sendtoone/100040429645000120" class="btn btn-blue" data-tracking="ENQUIRY:SEND">Send Email</a>
<a itemprop="url" rel="nofollow noopener" href="http://www.redplanetpizza.com" data-tracking="AP:CN:WL" target="_blank" class="btn btn-blue">Visit Website</a>
<div id="hideFullMap" class="btn btn-blue is-active utils-hidden" role="button" tabindex="0">Hide the Map</div><button id="showFullMap" class="btn btn-blue businessCapsule--mapDirections" data-stoplink="true">Map &amp; Directions</button><span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Map" class="utils-hidden"><span itemprop="url">https://www.yell.com/biz/red-planet-pizza-london-3432962/#view=map</span></span>
</div>
```

I'm pasting below my script I've written so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.yell.com/biz/red-planet-pizza-london-3432962/')
button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class, "btn-blue")]')[2]
button.click()
print(button.text)
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
Email: Send Email
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Thanks sir  Andersson, for your kind response. Actually, I didn't find any email id in that page while inspecting element and viewing source code. Pressing the send email-button I could notice that it creates ajax response. However, if I try to convey any message via send button, it does get transferred and that is why I thought it was possible to retrieve that email id by catching the response where it goes. I don't know the email id, sir. Thanks again.

Comment: I still not sure I can understand your goal, but I see that you're trying just to send `GET`-request to receive a simple `HTML` document. You should try to send `POST` request that will simulate clicking `Seng Email` button and then parse pesponse. I guess required email ID should be there

Comment: Yes it is sir. It is exactly what you said. I'm just a starter so don't get me wrong if I misled you with my given information. I never worked with post request that could simulate clicking. Thanks again sir.

Comment: Check your "Network" tab on developers console when you clicking the "Send Email" button- you should send exactly the same request using `requests` package. You can copy this requests details and share them with us if you don't know how to send the request

Comment: Thanks again sir Andersson, for your response. If I could understand you properly then this is what I get pressing the send button in the dev tool. "https://www.dropbox.com/s/sgoot309rr8yq9i/Requests.txt?dl=0"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148166/discussion-between-andersson-and-smth80).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, sir Andersson has provided me the answer through different suggestions. This answer is for those who stumble across such problem as i did here and happen to see this thread.

```
import requests

link = "https://www.yell.com/customerneeds/sendenquiry/sendtoone/"
payload = {'message':'Testing whether this email really works.','senderPostcode':'GL51 0EX','enquiryTimeframe':'withinOneMonth','senderFirstName':'mth','senderLastName':'iqbal','senderEmail':'habibrahman@gmail.com','senderEmailConfirm':'habibrahman@gmail.com','uniqueAdId':'100040429645000060','channel':'desktop','ccSender':'true','marketing':'on'}
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.post(link, data = payload, headers = headers)
email_elem= response.json()
email_ID = email_elem["emailToCustomerUUID"]
print(email_ID)
```

And here is the result:

```
Email-ID: 5a255d5f-3cc5-491d-87ac-9d21e652ec4b
```